# Field label not shown in actionRegion

Tags: visualforce, actionregion

I'm a beginner in Salesforce and I have a problem with the "actionRegion" component. It turns out that the field wrapped into the component doesn't show the label.
I've found on the web that other people had the same problem as me, but even following the advice, nothing has changed.

Here is the code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" extensions="ProjectController">  
  <apex:sectionHeader title="New project" subtitle="Create a Project (VF Page)"/>
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Project Info">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveNew}" value="New Project"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" id="pbs1" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!project.Name}" />
        <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
            <apex:inputField value="{!project.Status__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pbs1" />
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        ....
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: post a screenshot please;

Answer (score 0):

Just add the label yourself by adding an outputLabel like below. Simply add an `id` to the input field and reference that as the field the outputLabel is for. Here are two examples depending on how you are trying to label the field. Example one on the left is if you want it with the salesforce styling, the one on the right is just adding a raw input field.

[image]

Left Example In PageBlockSectionItem:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel for="projectStatus" value="Status "/>
        <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
            <apex:inputField value="{!project.Status__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pbs1"/>
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:actionRegion>           
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Right Example as standard input:

```
    <apex:actionRegion immediate="true">
        <apex:outputLabel for="projectStatus" value="Status "/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!project.Status__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pbs1"/>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:actionRegion>
```